# Return value from lambda function in background thread, throw NullPointerException

Tags: java, multithreading, lambda, concurrency, runnable

In my use case, I want to return a user object from the lambda function as in the code below. Before posting my question, I try many similar questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48335425/returning-from-lamda-expression) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38540481/return-value-by-lambda-in-java) but no theme solves my problem, here is my code:

```
public class User {
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

public class AppDatabase {

    private static final int NUMBER_OF_THREADS = 4;

    public static final ExecutorService databaseWriteExecutor =
            Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NUMBER_OF_THREADS);

}

public class MyClass {

    private User mUser;

    public User findUser(){
        AppDatabase.databaseWriteExecutor.execute(() -> {
            mUser = work();
        });

        return mUser;
    }

    public User work(){
        //simulate get user from database
        User user = new User();
        user.setName("Toto");
        return user;
    }
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
        User user;
        user = myClass.findUser();

        System.out.println(user.getName()); //this line: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    }
}
```

When I run this code, I get "Exception in thread" main "java.lang.NullPointerException". My question is how do I get the User object built by the work () function, but this function should run in a background thread like in code.

Comment: `findUser` returns right away, and it returns `null` because `mUser` hasn't been set yet. You need to either wait for it to be set, or return a `Future<User>` that the caller can wait on.

Comment: @DavidConrad Would you make an Answer of your Comment so it can be accepted to mark his page as resolved?

Comment: @BasilBourque Sure, although it feels a little sparse for an answer, and I may not have time soon to expand on it.

Comment: @DavidConrad, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`findUser` returns right away, and it returns `null` because `mUser` hasn't been set yet. You need to either wait for it to be set, or return a `Future<User>` that the caller can wait on.